# Jump to position using an adapterview

Tags: android, performance

I am using a custom adapterView with a Scroller to provide horizontal lists of items. I want to provide a quick way to jump to a specific index. I have fond a way to do so by calculating the pixel location and performing a fling. Unfortunately because every item between the start and end point are shown (and this is a data set in the thousands), this isn't all that fast. Is there a way to skip processing every n child views so the fling is faster or, if that isn't possible, is there a way to get a scroller to move to a specific location.

Comment: if you are having a ListView, you could use setSelection(int position) method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change to using a `ListView` and use `smoothScrollToPosition()`, or `setSelection()`. (Caution: `smoothScrollToPosition()` doesn't work properly on an ExpandableListView.)